# Less engaging trema or umlaut key combination

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

the current setting for a trema or umlaut diacritic sign on a character is generally to use a combination of Compose + : + character. This is not the best way to work on texts in the Albanian language, where the character ë (reads like the French œ) is perhaps the most frequent vowel of the language. Would there be a way to modify a QWERTY US or GB keyboard so that one can create ë-s by hitting only a Compose key and some single key on the keyboard?

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using? Maybe the basic _English (US)_ one?

Comment: Yes, I am using the English (US) keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the *English (UK)* layout, there is no need to use a compose key since it includes the `dead_diaeresis` symbol. Hence:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> followed by <kbd>E</kbd> => ë

As regards US, a trema can be added in a similar way if you for instance use the *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* keyboard layout.